# Why isn't ray optics applicable for marginal rays?

Tags: visible-light

I have been studying light and going a little bit ahead I studied about ray optics and one thing each book had in notes is ray optics is applicable only for paraxial rays not marginals rays, I was wondering why not for marginal rays. I googled it and got answer but their language was very complexed and I simply could not understand them

Comment: Please answer quick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your book is talking about the [paraxial approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation), which supposes that $\sin(x)\approx x$ (this is motivated because you take the first term of the Taylor expansion $\sin(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$). As you can see, this is only valid for small angles.

But it's not true that ray optics is not valid for marginal rays, only that it's much more complicated. If you take $\sin(x)\approx x+\frac{x^3}{3!}$, [Seidel abberations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_aberration#Monochromatic_aberration) and other fancy stuff appear.

Comment: It is worth noting that angles *must* be measured in radians for this approximation to be valid.

Comment: @AadityaCool You're welcome, but please, don't beg people to answer fast.

Comment: Ok i will keep that in mind, i think I was being selfish